# Hadoop Command Not working while executing from c# code in Windows7, Error show : "Access is denied"

Tags: windows, hadoop, permissions

I am Executing Hadoop Command using `winutils.exe task create ip ipconfig` from cmd with Admin privileges its work and shows the result. But if am trying the same in c# program with Admin privileges it shows `Access is denied` error.

Error :

```
C:Hadoop\bin>winutils.exe task create ip ipconfig

createTask error (5): Access is denied.
```

Comment: So, winutils.exe is your c# program? Both the success command and error command above looks same to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the WinUtils.exe. WinUtils.exe used **AssignProcessToJobObject()** in the **createTask()** method in ***task.c*** file.

In windows 7, If the Jobobject has already a process assigned, then ‘AssignProcessToJobObject’ cannot assign a new process and returns with ‘Access Denied’ message.

[image: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681949(v=vs.85).aspx]
So when you called the exe programatically, the jobObject may be already assigned with a ProcessHandle which then returns as "Access Denied" from the 'AssignProcessToJobObject' function.

**Fix:** Check the JobObject for any associated processes and assign a new process only if the jobObject is not assigned to any. Ensure your changes apply only to the Windows 7 environment and let the default code to be used in the Windows 8 and greater environments.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @MarHserus can you show me how to check the JobObject as Kalai mention above? Can I have your modified version of task.c file? Thanks

Comment: MarHserus: here is my modified version of task.c https://gist.github.com/kholis/5b6f3bcbe36819bf03c5/revisions. It can compiled but got error while it running. @Kalai: need help. Thanks